# What's the compactness, connectedness and homotopy group of indefinite unitary group $U(p,q)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, lie-groups

$U(p,q)$ is a indefinite unitary group with $pq\not=0$.

Is it compact? If not, what's the maximal compact subgroup?

Is it connected? How much connnected components?

What's the homotopy group of its connected component?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?  Have you tried to answer any of these questions on your own?

Comment: Note: wikipedia has a page on the [indefinite orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group), and some of the ideas can be applied to the unitary group as well.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, I think $O(p,q,R)\subset U(p,q)$, so it is noncompact. I guess that the maximal comact subgroup is $U(p)\times U(q)$. But I cannot answer whether it is connected. And I guess the homotopy group is $\pi_1(U(p))\times \pi_1(U(q))$

Comment: @user34669, Did you find an answer?

Comment: @user34669, I'd wager it is not connected at least for the case p=q. Using the following argument: the identity matrix and diag(1,-1) are both in the group. Using the \det map we find a non-constant continuous function into {+-1}.

Comment: @PPR This argument does not work because $\mathrm{det}$ takes values on the unit circle, which is connected. For example $U(1,1)$ is diffeomorphic to $S^1 \times S^1 \times D$, where $D$ is the unit disc.

Comment: @user420261, right, I take it back. I guess for $U(n, n)$ one could use that this group is unitarily isomorphic to the Hermitian symplectic group. Then use the same argument as for the usual symplectic group to show that it is connected (this for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389610/the-symplectic-group-is-connected) or use an SVD-like decomposition of that group to path-connect any given matrix to the identity?